# How to add toggle full width search box to the Navbar in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am using Bootstrap 4, and i am trying to place a search box which toggles to full width when the icon is clicked.

In Bootstrap 3, it was done like this example:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-navbar-search

But I am not sure how to achieve the same in Bootstrap 4 as so much has changed in bootstrap 4.

How do i modify the above example?

Comment: Your snippet is too broad. Please, can you copy/paste the Bootstrap 3-compatible code **to do the toggle only** in your question ?

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer the issue i'm facing is that when i replace bootstrap 3 links with bootstrap 4 links the layout breaks and the full width doesn't take up the whole navbar

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com)? The Navbar classes and structure have changed so you'll need to adjust it as needed.

Comment: @Zim yeah i did i copied the bootstrap 4 navbar code from the docs added the search form from the example and seems like somehow something is still blocking the search from taking up the full width of the navbar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zaakirah/0rmpuqcj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Navbar as needed for Bootstrap 4. Notice the structure has changed. It now uses flexbox, the `input-group` classes, `nav-item`, etc.. are all different...

I used this [tool](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/) to convert the Navbar structure from 3 to 4. Then adjust the `input-group` classes...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light fixed-top navbar-expand-sm" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> ☰
        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown nav-item"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown nav-item"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider dropdown-item"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <span class="fa fa-remove">
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <span class="fa fa-search">
                        <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

You'll also need to modify the CSS. The padding for the buttons, height, etc..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        padding-top: 0px !important;
        padding-right: 38px !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
        width: 38px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
        font-size: 15pt;
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;  
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
    .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
        display: table-cell;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/mLnFOWZqVo

Comment: Wow thanks so much! this is perfect. Really appreciate it